# PyCharm inputs throwing error and not working

Tags: kernel, pycharm, jupyter

I am having a trouble to run any input in PyCharm, I don't know if its about the Jupyter kernel or how to solve it?

If someone had this error before,could he tell me how he solved it?

Error Message:

```
StdinNotImplementedErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-5bbeab964ebf> in <module>()
----> 1 key = input()
      2 print key

/home/dremy/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.pyc in <lambda>(prompt)
    174             self._sys_eval_input = builtin_mod.input
    175             builtin_mod.raw_input = self.raw_input
--> 176             builtin_mod.input = lambda prompt='': eval(self.raw_input(prompt))
    177         self._save_getpass = getpass.getpass
    178         getpass.getpass = self.getpass

/home/dremy/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.pyc in raw_input(self, prompt)
    697         if not self._allow_stdin:
    698             raise StdinNotImplementedError(
--> 699                 "raw_input was called, but this frontend does not support input requests."
    700             )
    701         return self._input_request(str(prompt),

StdinNotImplementedError: raw_input was called, but this frontend does not support input requests.
```